# How to make protoc include .proto comments in Python

Tags: python, comments, grpc-python, protoc

I'm trying to figure out how to make my comments in my .proto file appear in the files generated for Python by protoc.

I have a proto file `service.proto`.
In it I have added comments on some of the messages as well as on some of the fields.
So for example:

```
// Comment regarding this message in general
message StepConfiguration {
    // Comment regarding this field
    bool skip_step = 1;
}
```

I have tried to execute the following command:
`python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I protos/V1/ --python_out=client/ --pyi_out=client/ --grpc_python_out=client/ protos/V1/service.proto`

This will generate the following 3 files:

- client\service_pb2.py
- client\service_pb2.pyi
- client\service_pb2_grpc.py

If I look through these 3 files, none of my comments carry over into them from the proto file.
Is there any way to configure protoc to do this? Or is there another tool I can use in combination with protoc to do this?

My main goal is for PyCharm to be able to present these comments when using the generated code.

Other information of possible relevance:

- When I generate C# classes in Visual Studio 2022 from a proto file, it will automatically include the comments from the proto file as XML docs on the generated items.

Answer (score 1):

to get comments for python generated code take a look at this plugin:
https://github.com/nipunn1313/mypy-protobuf

using official protoc compiller from google:
https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/

first install it to your code generator

```
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install mypy-protobuf
```

then use it to generate code:

```
mkdir -p client
protoc -I protos/V1/ --plugin=$PWD/.venv/bin/protoc-gen-mypy  --mypy_out=client/ --python_out=client/ --grpc_python_out=client/ protos/V1/service.proto
```

the comments in .proto will be provided as docstrings

the example file service.proto

```
// proto file global comment
syntax = "proto3";

// Comment regarding this message in general
message StepConfiguration {
  // Comment regarding this field
  bool skip_step = 1;
}
```

will result into following service.pyi:

```
"""
@generated by mypy-protobuf.  Do not edit manually!
isort:skip_file
proto file global comment"""
import builtins
import google.protobuf.descriptor
import google.protobuf.message
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    import typing as typing_extensions
else:
    import typing_extensions

DESCRIPTOR: google.protobuf.descriptor.FileDescriptor

@typing_extensions.final
class StepConfiguration(google.protobuf.message.Message):
    """Comment regarding this message in general"""

    DESCRIPTOR: google.protobuf.descriptor.Descriptor

    SKIP_STEP_FIELD_NUMBER: builtins.int
    skip_step: builtins.bool
    """Comment regarding this field"""
    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        skip_step: builtins.bool = ...,
    ) -> None: ...
    def ClearField(self, field_name: typing_extensions.Literal["skip_step", b"skip_step"]) -> None: ...

global___StepConfiguration = StepConfiguration
```